# How to correctly assign values in 2D array?

Tags: python, graph, data-mining

I am trying to assign a one hot encoding to each subset of the nodes in the graph.
Below is the code i am trying

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
graph=nx.karate_club_graph()
nodes=list(graph.nodes())
n=graph.number_of_nodes()
subset_nodes=[1,2]

for v in subset_nodes:
    y=nodes.index(v)
    prob_vec=np.zeros((n,n))
    prob_vec[0][y]=1
    print(prob_vec)
```

I am getting this result

```
[0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
[[0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]

I expect a matrix, with the subset nodes rows contains one hot encoding(1 value for each node in the subset node and others being zeros) like below:
[0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0.0 . 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: The first row need to be zeros also, since its the row for node 0 which is not in the subset nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you need to slightly adjust your code. You're currently printing each loop and resetting prob_vec to 0 each loop. I think you want to do something more like this:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
graph=nx.karate_club_graph()
nodes=list(graph.nodes())
n=graph.number_of_nodes()
subset_nodes=[1,2]

prob_vec=np.zeros((n,n))
for v in range(n):
  y = nodes.index(v)
  if y in subset_nodes:
    prob_vec[v][y]=1

print(prob_vec)
```

This outputs:

```
[[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]]
```